# Override JavaScript in base Flask template

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I have some JavaScript on [techtonica.org](http://techtonica.org) that checks for a cookie and pops open a newsletter subscribe form the first time the site's been visited. There's one page where we don't want the form to pop up, because that's where people are thanked for subscribing through a link we send to them. I could just not extend base.html, but I'd rather not have so much repeated code for the navbar and footer.

I tried just adding some script tags to the top of the template and setting `cookieExists` to true, but the popup still appeared and no error showed up in the console. How can I override part of a Flask template? Or how can I override the JavaScript in that one page?

- [The JavaScript is here](https://github.com/MichelleGlauser/techtonica/blob/master/static/js/index.js).
- [The base template is here](https://github.com/MichelleGlauser/techtonica/blob/master/templates/base.html).
- [The thank you template is here](https://github.com/MichelleGlauser/techtonica/blob/master/templates/thankyou.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the script in the base template with a Jinja block. In the template that you don't want it, override it with an empty block.

```
{% block subscribe_script %}
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block subscribe_script %}{% endblock %}
```